# Why do i see different security groups for different regions in AWS amazon console

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have made one EC2 instance in Asia-pacific region Sydney. I have two security groups there. Today when I logged into my console, the default region selected was "oregon". The security groups were different with different names.

I have the following questions:

1. Why do I have different groups for different regions? Can't I have the same security groups for all regions?
2. Does Amazon charge me more money for different regions? I only want to use Sydney region.

Answer (score 0):

1. you cant have same group for different region , as its a different data center .
2. Amazon wont charge you for creating security groups . you can create n number of groups .

Comment: no no , i mean if i have my instance in different region will that cost money. because i only want in sydney

Comment: obviously instance in other region will cost depend upon the instance type you choose

Comment: I have used micro instance. no no i mean to say that do i get cost for one region or i get charged for all regions as my instance is in all regions. i have only chosen sydney region when i created. how can i check that

Comment: once u login , you can see the region on right upper side of the console , you can switch the regions ,if you want to check other region instances

Comment: Ok , i mean to say that if we click on other regions , then am i suppose  to see the same instance everywhere in all regions but same cost. or Normally there is instance in one region only. if i see same instance in all regions then i will get charged more.

Comment: yes , this is because , instance cost is not same across all the regions. in simple words , small instance in Singapore region has different cost than Tokyo region's small instance .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32800/discussion-between-manjunath-bavihal-and-user1958218)

Comment: how can i stop my instance in other regions and turn on only in sydney